# Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'repository.RoleRepository' available

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm new in spring boot and I have a problem when i want to start the application, I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'repository.RoleRepository' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:347)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1107)
    at mereuta.marian.tennis01.Tennis01Application.main(Tennis01Application.java:23)
    ... 5 more
```

this my application code:

```
package mereuta.marian.tennis01;

import model.Horaire;
import model.Role;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import repository.HoraireRepository;
import repository.RoleRepository;

import java.sql.Time;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Tennis01Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context= SpringApplication.run(Tennis01Application.class, args);

    //  HoraireRepository horaireRepository=context.getBean(HoraireRepository.class);

        //horaireRepository.save(new Horaire(new Time(8, 0,0), new Time(22,0,0),"Lundi"));

        RoleRepository roleRepository=context.getBean(RoleRepository.class);

        roleRepository.save(new Role("client"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, try using `@Autowired` on `roleRepository` outside of `main` function and use another function with `@PostConstruct` to save something.

Comment: I find my error , it was because my packages was outside from the main package of java spring boot